# How to set up and transform a Camera in a SubScene?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, perspectivecamera

I am trying to get an isometric view of a grid. The grid is only part of the main scene so I created a subscene and I want add a camera to it. I will want to be able to zoom the camera in and out and pan it around preserving the viewing angle throughout all these operation.

Here is what I have without the camera:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Button actionButton = new Button("Placeholder\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
        HBox hbox = new HBox(actionButton);

        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane(new MyView(), null, null, hbox, null);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private class MyView extends Group {

        MyView() {

            super();

            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
                Rectangle tile = new Rectangle(30, 30, Color.GREEN);
                BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(tile);
                pane.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(null, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,
                                                           null, null, null)));
                grid.add(pane, i / 8, i % 8);
            }

            Group root = new Group();
            root.getChildren().add(grid);

            SubScene scene = new SubScene(root, 300, 300, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
            scene.setFill(Color.DARKCYAN); // just to see the area

            getChildren().add(scene);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Now I add the camera like this in the MyView constructor:

```
Camera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
scene.setCamera(camera);
```

and the grid disappears.

[image]

I didn't even do any transformation yet (i would do `camera.getTransforms().addAll(new Rotate(-15, Rotate.Y_AXIS));`). What am i doing wrong?

also, how can I tell the subscene to take whatever space is available? I don't want to need to specify specific size because the program can run on all sorts of screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your camera is positioned at the same `z` coordinates as the `Group`. However you have to make sure it's at a distance between `farClip` and `nearClip`:

```
PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
camera.setTranslateZ(-100);
camera.setFieldOfView(120);
```

Furthermore for isometric views **Perspective**Camera is the wrong `Camera` to use. Use `ParallelCamera` instead:

```
Camera camera = new ParallelCamera();
//camera.setRotationAxis(new Point3D(1, 1, 0));
//camera.setRotate(30);
scene.setCamera(camera);
```

> also, how can I tell the subscene to take whatever space is available?

Change the type extended by `MyView` to something that is resizable and bind the size of the `SubScene` to the size of `MyView`:

```
private class MyView extends Pane {

    MyView() {
        ...
        setPrefSize(300, 300);
        scene.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
        scene.heightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
    }
```